# collinearity of 3 points

Tags: geometry

Let's consider $A,B,C$ - 3 points in $R$x$R$. ( not in space )

If we want to determine the collinearity of the above points what theroem / definitions should we use?

1. if $AB $||$ d$ and $BC $||$ d$ => $A,B,C$ are collinear.
2. ( I would need a explanation for this, it seems so easy .. )

if one of $AB$,$AC$,$BC$ have the property that is the sum of others two segments. (e.g.: if $AC=AB+BC$ => $A,B,C$ are collinear )

What is the best practical method for demonstrating the collinearity of 3 points?

Comment: Find the slopes of $AB$ and $BC$, and they should be equal.(in  2D)

Comment: Are the points given to you in terms of coordinates? And are they in the plane or $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: The points are in plane ( R x R ), not in space

Comment: Then finding slopes should be enough.

Comment: We do not have the coordinates of the points, we only know the segments, AB = ... cm, BC = ... cm and so on.

Comment: Then one of the segments should be the sum of the other two segments. I don't think there is any other (easy) way to find that they are collinear

Comment: You only have the lengths of the segments?